# access of protected field from other class

Tags: java

For the below code, I can access the protected fields of a `SeatPlan` class and change its value from the `Classroom` class, which looks like not secure for those data.

Is this normal? Isn't it protected fields can be accessed by its subclass only? Otherwise I need to change them to `private` field?

---

Let's say I have an `abstract` class with `protected` fields:

```
public abstract class SeatPlan {
    protected int rowNum;
    protected int columnNum;

    public abstract void method();
}
```

Then it has child classes:

```
public class ASeatPlan extends SeatPlan {
    public ASeatPlan(){            // constructor
        this.rowNum= 10; 
        this.columnNum = 7;
    }
    // omitted code
}

public class BSeatPlan extends SeatPlan {
    public BSeatPlan(){            // constructor
        this.rowNum= 7;
        this.columnNum = 15;
    }
    // omitted code
}
```

A class `Room` contains a `private` field of `SeatPlan` object:

```
public class Room {
    private SeatPlan seatPlan;

    public Room(SeatPlan seatPlan){       // constructor
        this.seatPlan = seatPlan;
    }

    public SeatPlan getSeatPlan(){     // getter method
        return seatPlan;
    }

    //omitted code
}

public class Classroom {
    public SeatPlan doSomething(Room room){
        SeatPlan seats = Room.getSeatPlan();
        seats.rowNum = 99999;     <--------------- accidentally change the value ------

    //omitted code
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference among 'public', 'default', 'protected', and 'private'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/difference-among-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: You need to understand access modifiers.
A simple tutorial can be found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_modifier_types.htm
A simple solution for your code it's the the best solution, as you will need to know how to use the modifiers for every single Java project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing C# with Java.

In C#, `protected` stuff can only be accessed by subclasses. But in Java, `protected` stuff can be accessed in the same package or in a subclass.

That's why you can change the value of the seat plan from a classroom.

Is this not secure?

IMO, it is. I don't think you should change the row and column number of a seat plan.

How do I make it so that it's secure?

You should redesign your seat plan class. Here's a rough idea:

```
public final class SeatPlan {
    private SeatPlan(int rowNum, int colNum) {
        this.rowNum = rowNum;
        this.colNum = colNum;
    }

    private int rowNum;
    private int colNum;

    //You should add getters for rowNum and colNum here
    //But I'm lazy so I did not do it for you

    public static final SeatPlan PLAN_A = new SeatPlan(10, 7);
    public static final SeatPlan PLAN_B = new SeatPlan(7, 15);
}
```